# Next(question) Button does not work when replay is done

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

This is a small quiz app which I am making to learn JS. It works fine and gives the proper result, but when clicked replay, it displays the quizBox but the 'Next' button does not work. There is no console error and I am unable to understand where to look for the error in the code.

This is the jsFiddle link of the working app
https://jsfiddle.net/lifet/t20h6gw8/10/

js has both the script and the questions file
This is the Html for the quiz and result box

```
 <!--Start Quiz Box-->
       <div class="row quiz_box">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                       //other part of code
                    <!--Quix Box Footer-->
                    <footer>
                        <button class="next_btn">Next</button>
                       
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>         
        <!--End Quiz Box-->

        <!--Start Result Box-->
        <div class="row result_box">
            <div class="card col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            //other part of code
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="restart">Replay Quiz</button> 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Result Box-->
    </div>
```

This is the css for hiding and showing the result and quiz box respectively

```
.removeResultBox.result_box{
  display: none;
}
.removeResultBox.quiz_box{
  display: flex;
}
```

This is the js for replay function and next on click.

```
//----------------  restart Quiz-------------------//

const replayQuiz = resultBox.querySelector(".restart");

function showQuizBox(){}

replayQuiz.onclick=() =>{
    quizBox.classList.add("removeResultBox");// this displays the quiz box
    resultBox.classList.add("removeResultBox");// this hides the result box

    queCounter = 0;
    queNumber = 1;
    startTime = 15;
    widthValue = 0;
    userScore =0;

   showQuestions(queCounter);
   questionCounter(queNumber);
   clearInterval(timeCounter);
   clearInterval(counterLine);
   startTimer(startTime);
   startTimeLine(widthValue);

   nextBtn.style.display="none";

}
```

This is the next button onclick event

```
//go on to the next question
nextBtn.onclick=()=>{
    console.log("next");
    if (queCounter < questions.length - 1) {
        queCounter++;
        queNumber++;
        showQuestions(queCounter);
        questionCounter(queNumber);
        clearInterval(timeCounter);
        startTimer(startTime);
        clearInterval(counterLine);
        startTimeLine(widthValue)
        nextBtn.style.display="none";
    }
    else {
        showResultBox();
    }
}
```

I am stuck badly and would really appreciate any help. Thank you!!

Comment: Please update your post and include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also using a [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) would be nice.

Comment: I just added the jsfiddle link for the code. Sorry the css is bit too long

Comment: In the `showResultBox()` function you are redefining `nextBtn.onclick`. Try and show the results immediately after the quiz ends without modifying `nextBtn.onclick`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. When the next button is hit for the last question, then the quizBox hides and resultBox appears with the result immediately. I do not know how else to do it.

Comment: made following changes to the showResultBox() function as you suggested
```
function showResultBox(){
        resultBox.classList.add("showResultBox");
        quizBox.classList.add("showResultBox");
        const scoreText = resultBox.querySelector(".score_text");
        let scoreTag = '<span> You scored <p>'+ userScore+ '</p> out of<p>'+ questions.length +'</p> </span>';
        scoreText.innerHTML = scoreTag;
}
```
and it works for the second time , but does not go further. The difference now is that it is hitting the next button but not doing anything. made changes in fiddle too

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the line

> const replayQuiz = document.querySelector(".restart");
> check the [website](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In `replayQuiz.onclick` instead of adding `removeResultBox` try and remove `showResultBox`:

```
replayQuiz.onclick = () => {
  resultBox.classList.remove('showResultBox')
  quizBox.classList.remove('showResultBox')
  ...
}
```